# cannot use my model on my controller " Undefined type 'App\Usuario' " Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I cannot use my model inside controller **Undefined type 'App\Usuario'** on Laravel.

When I try to, **create**, **edit** or **remove** an user I am getting error **Undefined type 'App\Usuario'** appears.

A few days ago the code worked for me but when I made another model called "paintings" they both stopped working. Maybe has some relation.

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Usuario extends Model
{

    use Notifiable;
    use HasFactory;

    // ...
}
```

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Usuario;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsuariosController extends Controller

{
    public function index()
    {
        $usuarios = DB::table('usuarios')
            ->select('usuarios.*')
            ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
            ->get();
        return view('usuarios')->with('usuarios', $usuarios);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $id = 0;

        // Validation ...

            $usuario = Usuario::create([
                'id' => $request->id,
                'nombre' => $request->nombre,
                'email' => $request->email,
                'contrasena1' => Hash::make($request->contrasena1),
                'contrasena2' => $request->contrasena2,
            ]);
            return back()->with('UsuarioAgregado', 'Usuario agregado con éxito');
       
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $usuario = Usuario::find($id);
        $usuario->delete();
        return back()->with("El ususario se elimino correctamente");
    }

    public function editarUsuario(Request $request)
    {

        $usuario = Usuario::find($request->id);

        // Validation ...

            $usuario->nombre = $request->nombre;
            $usuario->email = $request->email;
            $validator2 = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'contrasena1' => 'required|min:7|required_with::contrasena2|same:contrasena2',
                'contrasena2' => 'required|min:7'
            ]);
            if (!$validator2->fails()) {
                $usuario->contrasena1 = Hash::make($request->contrasena1);
            }

            $usuario->save();
            return back()->with("El usuario se actualizo correctamente");
        
    }
}
```

Sorry if my English is not good.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCKnl.png

Comment: You seem to be missing the namespace at start of the model class.



namespace App;

Comment: Pleaz reformat your question! and tell what version of Laravel are you using if you can.

Comment: @MuhammadTashfeen OMG I LOVE YOU SO MUCH, THANK YOU. 
It fixed my problem. 
Now i have the same problem with "Pinturas" controller, i didnt make it using the console, could this be the problem?

Comment: "[CODE IMG AT THE END][1]" -- don't. Code should come as text, in many cases in the form of a [mcve], along with the output it produces, which should also be text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the class `Usuario` is located in the folder `App` this can be a Laravel 5 project.

the top of your model needs the namespace line

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Usuario extends Model
```

Comment: Thank u so much. It fixed my problem, now I have the same problem with "Pinturas" Model, i didnt make it using console, could this be a problem?

Comment: You can make your project files either manually or using **Artisan**. But the command line is the recommended way to avoid typo errors. like you did by forgetting the namespace. share you `painturas` class to get a solution

Comment: On my way medilies.
Oh i just fixed it, it was a similar error on my Model, thank u so much Medilies u helped me a lot, im making my final project of my grade formation.

Comment: @Esprulo lucky you for knowing how to use Laravel before your graduation :D. I did my graduation with PHP from scratch XD. good luck and don't forget to mark your question as answered/solved

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need to use this code on the header of your controller :

```
use App\Models\Usuario;
```

that's a common problem. it depends on the structure of your project's directory.